# how to insert multiple records from text to mysql db with php

Tags: php

how to insert many records to database from text area at one time instead of inserting them one after the other because it takes a long time if you have alot of records

1 - writing data to text area in this way

```
#fname-1980-74
#sname-1994-84
#lname-1990-54
```

2 - every line will be inserted to database as an Independent record

3 - this is the Best code And The Must Shortcuted Code that you have to use :

`$txt = "#fname-1980-74#sname-1994-84#lname-1990-54";`

`foreach (explode('#' , $txt) as $line) {
    echo $line = str_replace('-' , ',' , $line);
}`

My greetings for all .

Comment: and your teacher will be proud of you, when you rearch php.net maybe explode(), file(), preg_match() or what ever can be your friend

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$txt = "@fname-1980-74#@sname-1994-84#@lname-1990-54#";

// strip first @ and last #
$txt = substr($txt, 1);
$txt = substr($txt, 0, strlen($txt) - 1);

$values = array();
$parts = explode('#@', $txt);
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    list($name, $year, $number) = explode('-', $part);
    $values[] = "($name, $year, $number)";
}

$query = "
INSERT INTO mytable(name, year, number) VALUES
" . implode(',', $values) . ";";

echo $query;
```

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
$txt = "@fname-1980-74#@sname-1994-84#@lname-1990-54#";
foreach ( explode( '#', $txt )  as $line ) {
    $line = str_replace( '@' , '' , $line );
    if ( empty( $line ) ) continue;
    echo '(' . implode( ',', explode( '-', $line ) ) . ')'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

output:

```
(fname,1980,74)
(sname,1994,84)
(lname,1990,54)
```